# How do I describe higher language verb types?

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

For example, present tense is "God blesses you" but there is another form which is "God bless you" in which "bless" is a different verb tense.  What is that higher verb tense that we use in more formal or higher forms English.

Comment: What do you mean by "higher forms"? Also, I don't believe I have ever heard "God blesses you". Finally, "The Lord bless you and keep you;
The Lord make His face shine upon you,
And be gracious to you;
The Lord lift up His countenance upon you,
And give you peace." [Numbers 6:24-26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+6%3A24-26&version=NKJV)

Comment: I don't know how to describe "higher forms" in English, but in Korean, they are the top 4 of the 7 forms of speech.  They are forms reserved only when speaking of someone who is higher than you, like kings, God, princes, etc . . .

Comment: In short, English does not. One possible exception is the majestic plural (or [royal we](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we)).

Comment: It is not a higher form nor is it a different [tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense) (of which in English there are only two, present and past). It's a different [mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood).

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thanks, mood is indeed a better description of what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Blesses" is 3rd person singular present indicative. "Bless" (in this instance) is 3rd person singular present subjunctive.The subjunctive is used to express a wish or request.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the present subjunctive is seldom used anywhere but within idioms and set grammatical constructions: e.g. *so be it, whether it be, be that as it may, come what may, come morning, ensure that it be done, thy kingdom come, be it resolved that, etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Originally we said "May God bless you"

May is a modal verb as are must, should etc.

Comment: *God bless you* is, in fact, the original form.  *May God bless you* arose later as the subjunctive became less frequently used.